# Woocommerce how to get specific product quantity in php code

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am new to developing with woocommerce, and I recently found a way to display all of the names of my products and also the quantity. However, I was only able to display ALL of my products, and not just each one individually. If I try and remove the foreach loop, I get an error stating:
Undefined index: data in /filepath of folder.

If anyone has ever been able to display a single quantity of a product in woocommerce, please let me know!

```
$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
    
    foreach($items as $item => $values) {
        echo " ";
        
        $_product =  wc_get_product( $values['data']->get_id()); 
        echo "<b>".$_product->get_title().'</b>  <br> Quantity: '.$values['quantity'].'<br>'; 
        $price = get_post_meta($values['product_id'] , '_price', true);
        echo "  Price: ".$price."<br>";
    }`
```

I was able to display each of the name and quantity of each product. However, when I tried to reverse engineer the foreach loop, I recieved an error:
Undefined index: data in /filepath of folder.

Comment: Can you show the code where you are trying to get a single product

Comment: `foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item) {
    $quantity = $cart_item['quantity'];
}`